problem with connecting Firebase for Flutter
I am trying to connect my flutter project to android. But it's not working and I have been trying and trying to resolve it but fails miserably.
I'm kinda new to this app development sh**.
This is literally my first try to build a full stack app(even though it is by watching a tutorial)
I am expecting to run the project without debugging. But it's not happening since I'm not connected to firebase properly.
That is the error I'm getting
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1:.
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).

On the new version, one has to modify the build.gradle file themselves.
At the top of the file, have this old structure
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
      google()  // Google's Maven repository
      mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}
// Rest of the lines as they are


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1:.
Required by:
project :


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).

Do flutter clean then, flutter get and build the project.
